# Django using mongodb _id

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to use mongodb's self generated objectID, removing the django generated ID. How do I do this and will it cause an error that I don't know in the future?

My ID line in models.I deleted this ID.:

`id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`

I will using mongo ID:
 `_id:ObjectId("4864gh937m3oy3xa412w16a8")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help?

https://marcolcl.medium.com/custom-django-model-field-based-on-default-primary-key-d5d13dd61a1c

If you solved this could you add solution so others may know as well?

Also here:

https://marcolcl.medium.com/custom-django-model-field-based-on-default-primary-key-d5d13dd61a1c

You can specify something like:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    blog = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Blog,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share a tip for retrieving a record by using MongoDB's primary key (_id) in a Django model. If you're working with Djongo and MongoDB, you can add an _id parameter in your Django model to make this process straightforward.

Here's an example:

```
from django.db import models
from djongo.models import ObjectIdField

class User(models.Model):
     _id = ObjectIdField(primary_key=True)
     username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
     password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  
 existing_user = User.objects.get(_id=user_id)
```